# Chern-Simons equation of motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, lagrangian-formalism, field-theory, variational-calculus, chern-simons-theory

How do I get the equation of motion of the Chern-Simons Lagrangian below? Is there the product rule at work? Do I have to sum over the indices?

[image]

Comment: Yes, they are using Einstein summation convention. The second equation comes from taking $\delta L / \delta a_{\mu}$. The third equation is just from rearranging.

Comment: Thanks. But summing how? Over what index? There are three indices. How do I get two identical terms that sum up to make the 1/2 disappear? And where does the minus come from in the third equation? What role does the Levi-Civita symbol play?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Making the summation explicit, your lagrangian is
\begin{align}
\mathscr{L}= - \frac{\kappa}{2}\sum_{\mu, \nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}a_\mu \partial_\nu a_\lambda.
\end{align}
in spacetime dimension $n$. Varying the corresponding action $I =\int d^nx\, \mathscr{L}$  wrt to $a_\mu$, we get
\begin{align}
\frac{\delta I}{\delta a_\mu} = - \frac{\kappa}{2} \sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu a_\lambda.
\end{align}
To find stationary points of the action, we set $\frac{\delta I}{\delta a_\mu}=0$ to get to the equation of motion
\begin{align}
\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu a_\lambda = 0,
\end{align}
where we've divided through by the constant $\kappa /2$. Now observe that since
\begin{align}
\varepsilon^{\mu \nu \lambda} = - \varepsilon^{\mu \lambda \nu}
\end{align}
we can write
\begin{align}
0&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu a_\lambda + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu a_\lambda\\ &=
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\partial_\nu a_\lambda - \frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n}\varepsilon^{\mu\lambda\nu}\partial_\nu a_\lambda \\
&=\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n} \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}\left(\partial_\nu a_\lambda - \partial_\lambda a_\nu \right)
\end{align}
Finally, define
\begin{align}
f_{\mu \nu} = \partial_\mu a_\nu - \partial_\nu a_\mu.
\end{align}
so that the equation of motion reads
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{2}\sum_{\nu, \lambda = 0}^{n} \varepsilon^{\mu\nu\lambda}f_{\nu \lambda} = 0
\end{align}